# Node js Watson Speech to text to console Not working

Tags: node.js

When I started app on windows I get this error:

```
Error: Module did not self-register.
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:672:18)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ahmet\node_modules\line-in\index.js:2:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
```

I updated all modules 
I updated node 
I do everything but still this error

Comment: How did you install this package? Globally?

Comment: @DevanBuggay. Yes . Also I tried on linux but on linux that gives connection refused error I think its problem with line-in package